# Show table generation as it generates?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently generating a table using jQuery by appending rows etc to the table and then returning it. Is there any way to show the table as it generates? So basically populating it as it goes and using it as a way of showing progress.

```
ui.generate_tabs('content-tabs', content_container, domain_list, function(domain_id) {
                var table = jQuery('<table><thead><th>Backbone</th><th>Sequence</th></thead></table>');
                var tbody = jQuery('<tbody/>');
                table.append(tbody);

                var show_table = function(table) {
                    console.log(table);
                    return table;
                }

                for (let aacid of utils.map_iterkeys(aacid_str)) {
                        var tr = jQuery('<tr/>');
                        tbody.append(tr);
                        tr.append(jQuery('<td/>').text(aacid));
                        tr.append(jQuery('<td class="single-line-td"><code>' + aacid_str[aacid] + '</code></td>'));
                        show_table(table);
                };

                // // Job done
                progress_indicator.remove();
                return table;
```

Comment: Show your efforts. This is not a source writing service. Or google a little harder; there are so many examples out there.

Comment: Can you show your code? Are you generating the table completely before inserting it in the DOM? Make sure you add each row to the DOM step by step.

Comment: Unless you purposefully set a delay before each row appears they will show up before the human eye can grasp.

Comment: Yes I'm currently generating the table fully before inserting it into the DOM. A thought I have is to incrementally insert it into the DOM, so like every time   I add rows I will "return" the table and insert it into the DOM.

Comment: @JesseLuo Yes, that is what you should do. If you don't see the progress, you might run into what Angel Politis explained. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use either the native setTimeout() function or the jQuery .delay() method to let the browser process DOM rendering.

Instead of doing:

```
for(var n = 0; n < N_ROW; n++) {
  appendRow(n);
}
```

You'd do:

```
var n = 0,
    iter;

(iter = function() {
  if(n < N_ROW) {
    appendRow(n++);
    setTimeout(iter, DELAY);
  }
})();
```

Where 'DELAY' is expressed in milliseconds and may be 0 or any other arbitrary value. Note that even with DELAY = 0, the process is likely to take more time than the 'standard way'.

**Edit:**
Like others noticed, it probably doesn't make much sense unless you plan to slow it down on purpose (with, say, DELAY = 500) to show the user that *'Hey, look! I'm adding new rows!'*

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your ideas. I realized another method, which was basically I returned the table immediately (empty) and since the data I was using to generate rows was being fetched remotely, as the data came in, I appended the rows to the table so it added them as they came in, showing it as "progress". I didn't make it clear in my question that the generation of rows was more dependent on the speed of the actual data fetch, which is why I wanted it to show incrementally.

Thanks everyone!